# BitBucket pipelines - docker unauthorized: authentication required - Docker push with successful login

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

This issue applies to Bitbucket pipelines. I have seen the other related questions, and frankly the Bitbucket yaml and Dockerfile scripts work great when directly executed in bash terminal.

Just when executing the pipeline, it fails, right after successful login.

Here is my Yaml file:

```
# enable Docker for the repository
options:
  docker: true

# Start the pipeline
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Name the image and create a docker image
          - docker build -t "my_docker_id/my_app:latest" . 
          - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
          - docker push my_docker_id/my_app:latest
```

And my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install Python and related tools
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# Now use Pip to install Flask
RUN pip3 install flask

# Set the working directory to Ubuntu user home
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu

# Then copy the website folder to home folder
COPY . /home/ubuntu
```

The docker login succeeds:

```
docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD<1s
Login Succeeded
```

The pipeline fails on:

```
docker push my_docker_id/my_app:latest
```

Fails with:

`+ docker push cbrodock/corpsite:latest
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/cbrodock/corpsite]
bdca855fbe4a: Preparing
d147d767df7b: Preparing
f6aad432f761: Preparing
0da658ad5264: Preparing
84e11e4ededf: Preparing
50fd25888dad: Preparing
2cb0a11f65e0: Preparing
ad8ba289abb4: Preparing
33f1a94ed7fc: Preparing
b27287a6dbce: Preparing
47c2386f248c: Preparing
2be95f0d8a0c: Preparing
2df9b8def18a: Preparing
50fd25888dad: Waiting
47c2386f248c: Waiting
2cb0a11f65e0: Waiting
33f1a94ed7fc: Waiting
2df9b8def18a: Waiting
b27287a6dbce: Waiting
2be95f0d8a0c: Waiting
ad8ba289abb4: Waiting
unauthorized: authentication required`

If I execute the same exact steps in my bash terminal on MacOS, they execute fine and push succeeds.

Any ideas?

Comment: Things that might happen 1. shell where you login and shell where you make the push command might be totally different shell ... will you try `docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD<1s
Login Succeeded && docker push my_docker_id/my_app:latest`

Comment: If above doesn't work then, try a different tag other than `latest`.

Comment: Same issue: docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD && docker push my_docker_id/my_app:latest123
Login Succeeded...And then comes >> unauthorized: authentication required